# Rationale behind providing a key in useAsyncData function

Tags: nuxt.js

You need to provide a unique key in order to use `useAsyncData` data-fetching function in Nuxt3. [The documentation](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/usage/data-fetching/#useasyncdata) says it is "to ensure that data fetching can be properly de-duplicated across requests". But I still don't understand this point. Could someone elaborate on this reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think it means that Nuxt uses the unique key to prevent firing the data fetching twice both in the server side and the client side.

See:

- https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/gotchas

Answer (score 0):

According to my observations, this unique key in `useAsyncData` enables caching of requests from the application. Because of this, the data on the page was not updated when I went to another page and then returned back. Inserting random numbers into a string does not help, Nuxt 3 writes: Hydration node mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a unique key per fetch request. So, if you have parameters in your request that should yield different data, then you want to include those in the key.

Don't use random numbers, as the random number can be generated again on client side, resulting in mismatch with what was generated on server side.

Something simple like your URL route is often a decent unique key + maybe any query parameters or other dynamic elements.

Not having this unique but using something like "pageData" as a key caused a lot of issues on route change as the new page thought the data was already cached, yet the values/keys didn't align.